# Tranpose of a 1D Array?

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the transpose of a 1D array such as:

$$ [1, 7, -1, 6]^T $$

Would it be equivalent to

$$ 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    7 \\
    -1 \\
    6
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 0):

I would say that $$[1, 7, -1, 6]^T=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    7 \\
    -1 \\
    6
\end{bmatrix}$$

So the transposed vector is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
    7 \\
    -1 \\
    6
\end{bmatrix}^T=[1, 7, -1, 6]$$

Transposing a transposed vector is the same as the vector itself.